# Configuring access-lists on the outside interface of Cisco ASA Firewall don't work

Tags: networking

I have a Cisco ASA 5510 Firewall and on the outside interface that is connected to Internet I configured some rules that allows access to a specific Public IP address on the specific ports, but it seems that these rules don't work.

Comment: Hi I'm sorry but this question has so little information about what you have already tried, no one will be able to assist.  Please consider reading [Eric Raymond's guide to asking a good question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).  As for support, the question is off-topic for [so]; however, [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) is a good place for Cisco ASA support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network engineering.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to creating access list, you also need to associate them with interfaces using access-group command.